# What's the best way to handle insert unique, okay to overwrite?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, upsert

I want to maintain a Collection of geographical info for IP addresses.

```
var IpAddressSchema = new Schema({
ip: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
},
geo: Object
}, {
    strict: true
});
```

IPs should be unique. And if an IP already exists, it should overwrite the document.

```
function storeGeoToMongo() {
emitter.on('inRedis', function (geodata, ipString) {
        console.log('.... Store geoInfo to MongoDB for ' + ipString);
        IpAddress.findOneAndUpdate({
            ip: ipString
        }, {
            ip: ipString,
            geo: geodata
        }, { upsert: true }, function (err, document) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Successfully saved document');
            }
        });
    }
);
}
```

Is there anything above that should be improved? (Thanks, Neil.)

Comment: Interesting that you mention upsert but make no attempt to use it. Put simply you match on the unique value and either write where matched or create where is it not found. `.update()` and .`.findOneAndUpdate()` both do this.

Comment: Thanks Neil, but I'm trying to understand why an upsert is the right way to go. It seems like the code above is fewer steps.

Comment: Using "upsert" is a single and atomic step. The code above is not only unnecessarily lengthy but is also deeply flawed. You are not waiting for asynchronous operations like `.remove()` to complete before issuing other asynchronous  operations. I would have thought a simple prompt to "try it" would further your understanding.